# Jumping to source while editing scala with vim

Tags: scala, vim

I like to edit my scala code with vim because of the developmental state of the Scala plugin for Eclipse.  I find this is very suitable for most of my purposes, especially in a `screen` instance with continuous compilation (`mvn scala:cc` or `~compile` in sbt) in the bottom pane.

The feature I miss most is being able to jump to the source easily.  Does anyone know of a way to do this in vim?  It should be theoretically possible since all the dependencies are avaiable using maven/sbt.

This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626203/text-editor-for-scala, but that question is closed, and the answer was the use emacs, which I could only consider if [viper](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViperMode) actually makes any sense.

Edit: I wrote a [blog post](http://www.schmitztech.com/tech/archives/3) that explores using vim as a full-featured editor for scala.

Comment: Jump to source from where? From some location on vim, or from REPL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Ctags. Vim has build-in support for it(since Ctags was basically made for vim), but you need to [download the program](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/). Ctags doesn't come with Scala support, but you can [configure it to support it](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Simple-ctags-etags-support-td1939562.html)(not a Scala user myself, so I haven't tested it).

You use it to create a tags file for your source files, and than you can easily use it to get to the definition of any function/class/everything in your source code. `Ctrl+]` to jump to the tag under the cursor. `Ctrl+W` and then `]` to open the tag at a new window. `:tag xxx` to jump to the definition of xxx. And my personal favorite - `g` and then `]` to show a list of all available tags with that name, and lets you jump to the one you choose - or just use the list to review the declarations(perfect if you forgot what arguments a certain function accepts).

Comment: I use Vim exclusively when coding Scala and ctags is a huge help. I think I started off with the config you posted and added something else I found on the net. I can't exactly remember what or where now. Anyway, hoping it helps schmmd and others, here's my .ctags config file: https://gist.github.com/1274261